# TFF uses a lot of CPU

Tags: tensorflow-federated

When I run my code without TFF (training my model with model.fit()), I notice that use of CPU is 5 % and my code run GPU . But if I introduce TFF : aside GPU,  training takes a lot of CPU (order of 90 %) and a lot of memory, Knowing that I use:
Tensorflow Federated v 0.12.0
Tensorflow v 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to diagnose exactly what is going on without some more details of the training setup, but there are a few things to note:

- TFF uses the eager TensorFlow runtime by wrapping its function specifications (which are stored as `tf.compat.v1.GraphDefs`) as `tf.functions`, and therefore 
  by default *delegates to the eager TensorFlow runtime to find and use GPUs*. This is an aspect of the TFF runtime that the TFF team is in the process of investigating, but hasn't spent too much time optimizing as of yet. TFF at this point considers the use of accelerators as nice-to-have, but not fully guaranteed or supported, especially across possibly heterogeneous hardware/OS setups. You should see some speedup with available GPU over no available GPU (which you can test by [disabling GPU at the beginning of your training](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31135)), but we have no enforced guarantees at this point on what runs where.
- TFF stands up each FL client *in parallel*; effectively, this can mean that you may have as many copies of the client model in memory/executing at once as you have clients. In a real FL setting, these models would all be on different physical devices; in simulation, they may all share your CPU. TFF in general provides a distributed runtime, which is in the process of being made self-service. An early tutorial on this [can be found here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/high_performance_simulation_with_kubernetes.ipynb), but this may be overkill for your use case.

Taken together, it is unsurprising that TFF uses more of the CPU than a single copy of the model training in Keras. This is a fundamental fact of learning in the federated setting--there is a tradeoff between sequential and parallel computation--in some sense, its earliest antecedent (at least of which I am aware) is [Parallelized SGD](http://martin.zinkevich.org/publications/nips2010.pdf).